How to linearize the product between a discrete positive variable and a continuous variable limited between 0 and 1
Suppose we have a integer variable x and continuous variable y in [0,1]. What is the best way to linearize the product xy ?  The problem is that the x variable is limited by 0 <= x <= M and the value of M is high, so, the trivial solution of first discretize the x value using binary variables and then linearize the (binary x continuous) product is not feasible.

Welcome to OR.SE. Please, took a look at this link.

Search this forum with the term "bilinear". This question has already been asked numerous times here.

What is the range of your $x$ variable?

Thank you @Brannon for your comment, x is limit by 0<= x <= M.  The problem is that the value of M is high, so, the trivial solution of first discretize the x value using binary variables and then linearize the (binary x continuos) product is not feasible.

@YuriAbitbol, also please, take a look at this link.

There is no good way to linearize this. It is better to let the solver worry about this.

The McCormick envelope is a possibility but I was trying to escape the approximation issue.

A global solver will do this better than you can from the outside.
